# Is my simplistic understanding of a Qubit, Superposition and Entanglement correct?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-states

I've gone through a number of Lenny Susskind's lectures on entanglement (both just for the joy of it and to better understand quantum mechanics) where he delves into the idea of a qubit.

For the sake of this example, let's go with the magnetic moment of an electron which can be 0 or a 1 at measurement. I'll go with 2 qubits alongside the classical model as a comparison.

**Classical Bit Model**

A two bit system (00, 01, 10, 00) has for possibilities and can be described using **2 bits** of information.

**Qubit Model**

The Qubit model consists of the following:

```
a|00>
b|01>
c|10>
d|11>

a|00> + b|01> + c|10> + d|11> = 1
```

Where `a|00>`, `b|01>`, `c|10>`, and `d|11>` squared are complex amplitudes representing the probabilities of each state at measurement respectively. In this case, there are **4 bits** of information required to describe this system.

Subsequently, a 3 bit system would require **8 bits** of information (2^3) to describe.

**Entanglement** refers to the fact that **both bits** are described by **one** wave function when calculating the probabilities of each outcome. They no longer vary independently.

**Superposition** refers to the idea that the system is a linear combination of each state (akin to northeast in comparison to north and east separately) until the system is measured; after which it collapses into a single defined and possible state.

---

The classical model requires `n bits` to describe a system of `n bits`, whereas a quantum mechanical model requires `2^n bits` to describe a system of `n bits`.

Thus, a quantum computer requires an exponential amount of information to describe its state in comparison to an equivalent classical computer of the same bit number.

Comment: 4 bits of information only allows $2^4=16$ possible values. But in a two-qubit system $a,b,c,d$ can take infinitely many values; the only constraint is that the sum of the squares of their magnitudes must equal 1. How will you specify the state of a two-qubit system with only 4 bits ?

Comment: I may be a little too new to this world to comprehend your response fully, so bare with me here. When you say infinitely many values, are you referring to the 'preparations' that the qubits can be put into? That is to say, the total space of probabilities that a, b, c, and d can assume before a measurement occurs is in effect as infinite set of 4 probabilities (but of course made equal to 1).

Comment: Yes. In a two-qubit system each of $a,b,c,d$ can take any of infinitely many complex values, as long as $|a|^2+|b|^2+|c|^2+|d|^2=1$. Each of these sets of different values represents a different state for the two-qubit system. Whereas the classical two-bit system has only four different states - one out of $a,b,c,d$ is 1, and the rest are 0.

Comment: I assume though that once a QPU is put into a certain state prior to a computation, my assumption holds true though. The infinity occurs before the qubits are prepared.

Comment: Before a measurement the two-qubit system is in one of an infinite number of possible states, which are superpositions of the four classical states (and there are ways of “preparing” a two-qubit system into a superposition state, not just the four pure classical states). Immediately after a measurement the system “collapses” into one of the four classical states - we can never observe a superposition state directly. In either case, 4 bits of information is wrong - either too few before measurement or too many after measurement.

Comment: This somewhat breaks my understanding of how one can actually get a QPU to perform an actual calculation rather than just getting an output of random numbers. Is there a resource I can review to bridge my understanding here? By the way I really appreciate your time here. I quite hungry to know how quantum computers actually work.

Answer (score 1):

There's some problems with your suppositions:

$$a|00\rangle+b|01\rangle+c|10\rangle+d|11\rangle= \begin{pmatrix} a \\ 
b \\
c \\
d\end{pmatrix}$$

Which are just two different notations -- the complex linear combination is not simply 1. There's the **Measurement Postulate**, which would have that, upon measurement, the probability of measuring the pair in any particular state is $1.0$, given that a measurement had taken place -- but this is not simply the natural state of things.

$a,b,c,d$ are probability amplitudes, $a, b \in \mathbb{C}$ and $|00\rangle, |01\rangle,$ etc. form a basis representing the combination of two qubits in a pure state.

I'm not sure where you are gleaning these information quantities from. There's one analog I know of called **superdense coding** - a protocol with which one qubit in an entangled pair can be used to transmit two bits of information to a recipient. I know of no other metric for quantifying the amount of information contained in any quantum state.

You are correct, in the established notation. Entanglement is when you have a 2-qubit state that cannot be expressed in the computational basis, because a pair of arbitrary states taken together has, $$(a|0\rangle +b|1\rangle) \otimes (c|0\rangle + d|1\rangle)=\begin{pmatrix} ac \\ ad \\ bc \\bd \end{pmatrix}$$

and an operation like swapping $bc$ with $bd$ (which would correspond to $\text{CNOT}$, a controlled-NOT gate) can be constructed, but then the new state can no longer be expressed as a tensor product, like how we constructed it.

Your statement regarding superposition is correct.

There's no correct analog though with respect to digital information contents, though:

$$|\psi\rangle =\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b\end{pmatrix}$$ exists in a continuous Hilbert space, when discussing universal quantum computing.

Comment: I'm doing a bit of research before I return. I think the answers here are awesome but a bit beyond me at the moment.

Comment: @Kris Nielsen and Chuang or Kaye are pretty good reads. They're a bit beyond me too, but really only require some Linear Algebra to get a basic idea. Additionally, Microsoft's "QuantumKatas" may help understand the algorithms better if you're a bit more hands-on / good with coding.

Comment: I will give those a look and return to my question in the next week or so. I think my understanding improved a bit when looking at things like Hadamard gates and how they transform |⟩ into a superposition. A qubit is then just a so-called quantum wire that is in some linear combination throughout each 'gate' until measurement - after which is collapses. Although I still don't have a full view of how unknown probabilities lead to computability.

Comment: It should be obvious that having certain states, and manipulations means that QC is compatible with classical computing, AND/OR/NOT. The reach is easier to understand in terms of random algorithms, quantum algorithms add an additional layer, but randomness may be a computational resource as well: [Polynomial-identity testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_identity_testing) [Schwartz-Zippel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz%E2%80%93Zippel_lemma)

Answer (score 1):

The answer by meltyness is nice, and I would upvote it if I had rep here. Here are some more general and less mathematical ideas that may help you to look at this from a different angle.

Classical and quantum information are fundamentally different things, and they're not freely interconvertible. Quantum information is a higher grade of information. It's sort of like in thermodynamics, where mechanical work is a higher grade of energy than heat. You can convert work into heat, but you can never completely convert heat into work. A more formal way to state this is that you can't in general transmit quantum information over a classical channel.

A good way to see this is to think about the fact that you can take a qbit and smoothly transform it from one basis state (say spin up) to another (say spin down), and you can do this through a transformation that involves only pure states (i.e., we're not talking about ensembles of electrons but just *one* electron). How would you represent this continuous change using any finite number of classical bits? A classical memory can only be in a finite number of states.

We can also get at this through the no-cloning theorem. It's not possible to make a separable copy of an unknown, pure quantum state. Doing so would violate unitarity, since it would erase the information of the system being overwritten with the copy. Well, if you could transform quantum information losslessly into classical information and then back, then you could just make the classical version, copy it as many times as you liked, and then transform the copies back to quantum -- which would violate no-cloning.

It's really not that surprising that we can't read out a quantum state as classical information. If we could, then we could get absolute phase information about a system. For instance, I could read out the state of a hydrogen atom as quantum information, convert it to classical, and write down the whole thing, including phase, on a piece of paper. Then I could wait some amount of time while the phase spun around as required by the Schrodinger equation, $E=\hbar\omega$, and record the new phase. But that doesn't make sense. The energy E is only defined up to an additive constant. The only way to get information about a phase like this is to interfere my hydrogen atom with *another* hydrogen atom, which gives only probabilistic results about their *relative* phases.

When you read out results from a quantum computer, you're doing a measurement. Due to decoherence, all you get from a measurement is an eigenvalue of the observable you measured. If you measure a qbit to be spin-up, then that's all you get. You can't tell what was the amplitude of the spin-down part before the measurement or the relative phases of the two parts of the superposition.